# Multivariable Calculus Limits

Tags: multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}= \frac{xy^3}{x^2-x^4 + y^4}$$

This is one of the limits that I have been tasked with calculating and I have tried searching similar limits on this website so I can learn how to solve this but I haven't found any... Also, I haven't been taught conversion to polar coordinates which might have made this easier.

My best guess so far has been to use the sandwich theorem with the $|xy^3|$ on either side but that computes it to be zero and I'm not very sure of this method.

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3 + y^4}{x^2 + y^4}$$
And this is the second one:

Now I did find a similar question to this but the method and answer were vastly different. Here I am thinking of using the two-path method with $x=0$ and $x=y$ which shows that the limit diverges (DNE). Would that be correct?

Comment: Note that DNE is not equivalent to divergent.

Comment: Yes, you should check that whether the limit is same, when approached from different directions, and if the limits are not the same, then the limit of the given expression does not exist.

Comment: For the second one, they are not the same so I guess that is sorted but what about the first one?

Comment: @AhsonYousef Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

First, let's restrict $x$ so that $|x|<1$.  Then, $x^2-x^4>0$ and by the AM-GM inequality we have

$$y^4+(x^2-x^4)\ge 2y^2\sqrt{x^2-x^4}$$

Therefore, we assert that

$$\left|\frac{xy^3}{y^4+x^2-x^4}\right|\le \frac{|y|}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}\to 0 \,\,\text{as}\,\,(x,y)\to (0,0)$$

Comment: I haven't studied AM-GM inequality yet and I was looking for more of a confirmation for my "attempt" at a solution: Sandwich the functions on both sides by $|xy^3|$ and take $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}$ which evaluates to be $0$ thus, since the limit of the function is sandwiched on both sides by $0$ hence the limit is $0$. Does this use of the sandwich theorem for multivariable limits make sense and is it legitimate?

Comment: Well, you don't really need the general AM-GM inequality.  Just note that $(a-b)^2\ge 0\implies a^2+b^2\ge 2|ab|$.  I am not sure what you did with the denominator term, which also goes to $0$.

Comment: I apologize I haven't been on this website for a while but here is the solution that I came up with which very much matches yours and perhaps that makes yours absolutely correct as well. $$When \ |x| \leq 1/(x)^{1/2}, x^2 \leq 1/2\ so \ x^4 \leq x^2/2$$ and then I compared it with $$\frac {xy^3}{\frac{x^2}{2} +y^4}$$ which is $=0$

Comment: @AhsonYousef I don't see how your solution works.  If $|x|\le x^{-1/2}$, then we must have $x\ge 0$.  And then we can only conclude that $0\le x \le 1$ and of course then $x^4\le x^2$.

Comment: @AhsonYousef Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $x^4=o(x^2)$ when $x\to 0$ so we can basically ignore the $-x^4$ term on the denominator.

Assuming we have $x^2+y^4$ then it is advantageous to set $u=\frac y{\sqrt{x}}$ .

After substitution we arrive to $f(x,y)=\dfrac{u^3\sqrt{x}}{1+u^4-x^2}$

Since $x\to 0$ we can assume $|x|<\frac 12$ and $|f(x,y)|<\underbrace{\left|\dfrac{u^3}{\frac 34+u^4}\right|}_\text{bounded}\times\underbrace{\sqrt{x}}_{\to 0}\to 0$

*Rem: the term $|g(u)|$ is continuous (since denominator does not annulate) of limit zero at infinity, thus bounded.*